# ImportError: No module named "webisite_dj"

Tags: python, django, powershell, pycharm

I am getting an below error while running manage.py run server.

Directory: C:\Users\home\Desktop\website_dj>ls

557 manage.py

PS C:\Users\home\Desktop\website_dj> python manage.py runserver

ImportError: No module named 'website_dj'

Comment: This error is not with python package. This might be from your directory. Have you included the `__init__.py` file ?

Comment: yes i have include but still i am getting same error.

Comment: `website_dj` is your directory name right ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered 'website_dj' in your installed apps in settings.py?